# Failed to get the output from a function

Tags: c

I have created a function to generate the id automatically. The input will be a previous id and the address of a new id.

```
void autoGenerateIDs(char prev_id[6], char* new_id[6]) {
    char numInID[5];
    int num;

    // Copy the number inside the ID
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        numInID[i - 1] = prev_id[i];
    }

    // Convert the string into number
    num = atoi(numInID);

    // Number plus one
    num++;

    // Convert the number into string
    itoa(num, numInID, 10);

    
    strcpy(*new_id, prev_id[0]);
    strcat(*new_id, numInID);
}


typedef struct {
    char id[6], name[10];
}Stud;

void main() {
    Stud student[2] = { {"A1001", "Justin"}, {"A1002", "Justin"} };
    char id[6], new_id[6];
    strcpy(id, test[0].id);

    autoGenerateIDs(id, &new_id);
}
```

But I get an [Error at the last line of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBgDc.png) when I run it.

However, when I try to run like below it works.

```
void main() {
    Test test[2] = { {"A1001", "Justin"}, {"A1002", "Justin"} };
    char id[6], new_id[6], numInID[6];
    int num;
    strcpy(id, test[0].id);

    //autoGenerateIDs(id, &new_id);

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        numInID[i - 1] = id[i];
    }

    num = atoi(numInID);


    num++;
    itoa(num, numInID, 10);

    strcpy(new_id, "S");
    strcat(new_id, numInID);

}
```

Is there any problem in these two lines`strcpy(*new_id, "S");` `strcat(*new_id, numInID);`

Comment: You allocate 6 bytes for the new ID and then want to copy into it the previous ID (no, strcpy doesn’t copy a single character just by using [0]) which is 6 bytes (max) and then the other array, which is 5 bytes max, so including nulls in both it’s 10 bytes into space of six. If you want just one character then assign it directly and strcpy the rest to one byte after.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks for the information! I will try to fix it. :D

Comment: You don't null-terminate `numInID` before pqssing it to `atoi()`.  That's undefined behaviour.